# how to convert this [('BAJRA',) , ('BARLEY',)] into list [BAJRA, BARLEY]

Tags: python

I have done below one, Is any way to do this effectively ?

```
foodlist2=[]
foodval = Foods.objects.values_list('Food')
for foodlist in foodval:
    for foodlist1 in foodlist:
        foodlist2.append(foodlist1)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No conversion needed if you just ask Django for the flat values with flat=True.

```
foodval = Foods.objects.values_list('Food', flat=True)
```

Comment: You shouldn't answer obvious duplicates. Close them as a duplicate instead. With over 100k rep you should know better.

Comment: It is honestly easier to answer something like this than to try and search for the best duplicate.

Comment: <QuerySet ['BAJRA', 'BARLEY']> how to remove QuerySet from this

Comment: Cast it with `list()`.

Answer (score -1):

you have a list where each element is a tuple that contains a single string.

so say you have

```
x = [('thing1',), ('thing2',)]
```

if you use list comprehensions like

```
x1 = [k[0] for k in x]
```

will give you

```
x1 = ['thing1', 'thing2']
```